Is every dense subspace of a separable order topological space over a dense order separable?
Let $X$ be a dense totally ordered set and $(X,\tau_X)$ be the order topology on $X$. Suppose $(X,\tau_X)$ is separable. $Y\subseteq X$ is dense on $(X,\tau_X)$, and $(Y,\tau_Y)$ is the subspace of $(X,\tau_X)$. Is $(Y,\tau_Y)$ necessarily separable?
Let $D\subseteq X$ be a countable dense set. $\forall d\in D$, we can find some elements in $Y$ close enough to $d$ so that we can construct a dense set in $Y$. But I am not sure if this idea works.

Every separable LOTS (= linearly ordered topological space) is hereditarily separable (= each subset is separable). In fact, this holds even in the class of all GO-spaces (= subspaces of LOTS). For the non-trivial proof, see here, (2.10).

For each pair of points in $D$, choose a point in $Y$ between them. This gives a countable subset $E$ of $Y$; I claim it is dense.
To see this, choose a point of $Y$ and a basic neighborhood $(a,b)$ in $X$. $(a,b)$ contains two points of $D$, and thus contains the point of $E$ between them.
